# Using Apache with another web server

Tags: apache

On my system I have more than one web daemon running, one of them is Apache which is listening on ports 80 and 443.  Another only accepts local connections on a different port.

Is it possible for Apache to forward connections to another daemon, wait for the reply before sending it back to the original client?

Possible config file could look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName another-hostname.com
    ForwardConnectionTo localhost:4949

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: One typical scenario was to run the Apache server on port 80 for the web  and some apps in Tomcat in port 8080 that does not need administrative rights. Then you would configure apache to retrieve some pages from tomcat and proxy them to the 80 port.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ProxyPass`. Make sure you have `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName another-hostname.com
    ProxyPerserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4949

</VirtualHost>
```